# Ubuntu not mounting connected hard drive but shows using fdisk

Tags: ubuntu

I have hdd connected to my single board computer running ubuntu bionic .

```
Disk /dev/sda: 74.5 GiB, 80026361856 bytes, 156301488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdd1c3393

Device     Boot    Start       End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             63  11727449 11727387  5.6G 12 Compaq diagnostics
/dev/sda2  *    11727450  90413819 78686370 37.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       90413820 156296384 65882565 31.4G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       90413883 156296384 65882502 31.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

The above shows up when i use `fdisk -l` command.
But these are not showing if i use `df -h` command.

Do i need to install something on my fresh ubuntu install for these partitions on external disk to be detected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before a partition shows up in df -h, it needs to be mounted.
To mount /dev/sda2, use the following commands.

```
mkdir /mnt/sda2
mount -t auto /dev/sda2 /mnt/sda2
```

Your files will then be accessible at /mnt/sda2.

To have these partitions auto mount when the device is plugged in, you can follow this guide.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB

Comment: But will this be automatically mounted again on rebooting?

Comment: I tried and got error saying /dev/sda2 commanf not found

Comment: There should be 2 commands to run, the mkdir command, and the mount command.